# on new user login, RTK Query not fetching the latest data, instead returning cached data

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, react-typescript, rtk-query

```
    export const presentationApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "vsl/api/v1",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: BASE_URL,
        prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
            const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
            if (token) {
                const { exp }: { exp: number } = decode(token);
                //token has expired
                if (exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
                    localStorage.clear();
                } else {
                    headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
                }
            }
            return headers;
        },
    }),

    // AUTH ENDPOINTS
    signin: builder.mutation<any, Partial<any>>({
        query: (body) => ({
            url: `/auth/login`,
            method: "POST",
            body,
            providesTags: ["Auth"],
        }),
    }),

    signout: builder.mutation<any, undefined>({
        query: () => ({
            url: `/auth/logout`,
            method: "POST",
            invalidatesTags: ["Auth", "Presentations"],
        }),
    }),

    // PRESENTATION ENDPOINTS
    getAllPresentations: builder.query({
        query: () => ({
            url: `/presentation`,
            method: "GET",
            cache: "no-cache",
            providesTags: ["Presentations"],
        }),
    }),
});
```

using     "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",

```
   const [signout, { data: response, isLoading, isError, isSuccess }] = useSignoutMutation();

   const signingOutRef = React.useRef<boolean>(false);

   const handleLogout = async () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    console.log("Before purge:", store.getState());

    // await persistor.purge();
    // await persistor.purge();
    // await persistor.purge();

    // persistor.flush();

    // console.log("After purge:", store.getState());
    // console.log('logout response',response);
    signingOutRef.current = true;
    signout(undefined);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (signingOutRef.current) {
      if (isLoading) {
        notifyLoading("Wait!", "Logging out...");
      }
      if (isSuccess) {
        dismissNotifyAll();
        // navigate("/auth/signin");
        window.location.href = "/auth/signin";
        makeRefFalse();
      }
      if (isError) {
        dismissNotifyAll();
        notifyWarning("Oops!", "Something went wrong. Please try again.");
        makeRefFalse();
      }
    }
    
  }, [isLoading, isError, isSuccess, navigate, signingOutRef.current]);
  
  //had to use it taht way. otherwise it was not working
  const makeRefFalse = () => signingOutRef.current ? (signingOutRef.current = false) : false;
```

had to deliberately reload the page with window.location.href. not even the persistor.purge working.
first i was not using the logout api, but then i had to make it so that rtk query can invalidate the `Presentation` tag. but turns out to don't have any impact and success.
If any of you guy wants to  come at the remote session i can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Signin does not invalidate the tag in your code. Change

```
    signin: builder.mutation<any, Partial<any>>({
        query: (body) => ({
            url: `/auth/login`,
            method: "POST",
            body,
            providesTags: ["Auth"],
        }),
    })
```

with

```
    signin: builder.mutation<any, Partial<any>>({
        query: (body) => ({
            url: `/auth/login`,
            method: "POST",
            body,
            invalidatesTags: ["Presentations"],
        }),
    }),
```

And please note that calling people to a remote session is not an appropriate behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for realisation. 
btw changing the tag didn't resolve the issue and still RTK not making an api call on signin and.